# Redirect parent document

Tags: javascript

I need to use Javascript  for redirect page.

I want user to click a hyperlink which using JavaScript would redirect the parent document to a new URL.

i try to use below code but not work, anybody can give advisee ? many thanks

```html
<p align=right style='text-align:right'>
  <span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:Verdana'>
    <a href="JavaScript:parent.document.frames.left.location.href='../xxx1.htm'; location.href='../xxx2.htm';">
      <span style='text-decoration:none;text-underline:none'>
        <img border=0 width=150 height=75 id="_x0000_i1025" src="../Images/xxx.gif">
      </span>
      <br>
    </a>
  <o:p></o:p>
  </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I really understood your requirement, but I guess you can try this ( or replace `location.href` with `src` property when iframes are concerned):

```
...
<a href="#" onclick="redir(event);">
...
<script>
    function redir(event){
        var base = event.target;
        base.parent.document.frames.left.location.href = '../xxx1.htm'; 
        base.location.href = '../xxx2.htm';       
    } 
</script>
```